# How to find/edit a standard field in NetSuite?

Tags: netsuite

I want to add a character limit to the first ship line of a customer address. How do I find the standard fields in NetSuite so I can edit them?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is that you can't make these types of changes directly to the native fields.

You will need to add a workflow or a script to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

- Navigate to your Home page.
- Click to the *Set Preferences* link.
- Check the *Show Internal IDS* box & save.
- Open the record that has the field in question.
- Click on the field name.  This will bring up a popup with the information and the field's ID.  That ID is what you reference the field by.

Now that you have the ID, you can write up a client script that simple monitors the data in the field.  I would use the On Field Changed trigger.  Just check to see if the length is less that your max, if not, return false with a popup or other notification.

You can also get more a little advanced and monitor the count while typing, and return false on the key press if they reach the max count.